# Create a X*Y array using input from user

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm quite new to python and is struggling with the basics.

Lets say user provides 221234 as input which I'm taking using `input()`
The first 2 numbers in that input, 2 and 2 will be taken as x and y for the array. The remaining 1234 will be the elements of array.

I have managed to use `pop()` to get the first and second value and store it to x and y.

```
x=list(value).pop(0)

y=list(value).pop(1)
```

Using slicing I managed to get the elements as well

```
elem=value[2:]
```

> **Now, how will I create a an array with size x and y having elements 1234 in it?**

I know for ex: 
`arrsize= np.zeros((x,y))` will create me an array with 2 rows and col. But then how will I pass the elements into that declared array?

Thanks,
Arjun

Comment: Obviously your code is limited to use only single digit numbers. Why not ask the user to input comma or space separated numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For single-digit input, you can just unpack the characters/digits in the string, since iterating over a string will give you the single characters:

```
import numpy as np

x, y, *v = map(int, input())
a = np.array(v).reshape(x,y)
```

As a short explanation, using `x, y, *v` on the left-hand-side of the assignment will unpack the right-hand-side, so that the first element is assigned to `x`, the second element to `y`, and the rest (denoted by the `*`) to `v` as a `list`.

If you ever decide to use separators between the numbers of your input, replace `map(int, input())` with `map(int, input().split(sep))`, where `sep` is your separator.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That is a good explanation!. Didn't even know I could assign values like that

Answer (score 0):

If your inputs are always single digits, try this:

```
inp = input('Enter dim and val: ')
lst = list(inp)
x,y = lst[:2]
arr = np.array(lst[2:], dtype = int).reshape(int(x),int(y))
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
Enter dim and val: 221234
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```